# ExceptionHandling Library Using SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot

I am using SpringBoot for creating Services. Now for Exception Handling (Using @COntrollerAdvice), I am trying to create a library instead of creating same files in each Service. This is my Exception Handler

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomExceptionHandler.class);

    /*
     * This handles constraint voilation exception.
     * @param exception
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleConstraintVoilationException(ConstraintViolationException exception){
        logger.info("Inside SumsExceptionHandler.handleConstraintVoilationException()");
        ValidationErrorResponse validationResponse = null;
        for(ConstraintViolation<?> constraintViolation : exception.getConstraintViolations()) {
            validationResponse = this.makeValidationResponse(constraintViolation);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(validationResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    /*
     * This handles MethodArgument Type Mismatch Exception.
     * @param ex
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleMethodArgumentTypeMismatchException(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException exception){
        logger.info("Inside SumsExceptionHandler.handleMethodArgumentTypeMismatchException()");

        ValidationErrorResponse validationResponse = new ValidationErrorResponse();
        validationResponse.setField(exception.getName());
        validationResponse.setCode(exception.getRequiredType().getSimpleName());
        validationResponse.setMessage(exception.getValue()+" must have valid input of type "+exception.getRequiredType().getSimpleName());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(validationResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    /*
     * This handles Missing Servlet Request Parameter Exception.
     * @param ex
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(MissingServletRequestParameterException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleMissingServletRequestParameterException(MissingServletRequestParameterException exception){
        logger.info("Inside SumsExceptionHandler.handleMissingServletRequestParameterException()");

        ValidationErrorResponse validationResponse = new ValidationErrorResponse();
        validationResponse.setField(exception.getParameterName());
        validationResponse.setCode(exception.getParameterType());
        validationResponse.setMessage(exception.getMessage());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(validationResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    private ValidationErrorResponse makeValidationResponse(ConstraintViolation<?> constraintViolation) {
        String fieldStr = constraintViolation.getPropertyPath().toString();
        String field = null;
        if(fieldStr != null) {
            String[] fieldArr = fieldStr.split("\\.");
            field = fieldArr[fieldArr.length-1];
        }
        return new ValidationErrorResponse(field,
                constraintViolation.getMessageTemplate(),
                constraintViolation.getMessage());      

    }
}
```

a) How do I create it a stand-alone library?(This is also a springboot Project)
b) How to then use it in other Projects?

Answer (score 0):

a) How do I create it a stand-alone library?(This is also a springboot Project)

- Create separate project with minimum dependencies.

b) How to then use it in other Projects?

- Build that project, Use that project as a library by adding jar in classpath

According to the [documentation](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/):

> Spring Boot makes it easy to create stand-alone, production-grade
>   Spring based Applications that you can "just run".

Answer (score 0):

You can also use maven to generate a new package with the required dependencies, then you can add the dependency in pom.xml. Gets a lookup on creating dependencies with Maven.

Answer (score 0):

- create a new  Maven Java Project with version and artifact Id  ...
  will package it as a jar
- add your needed dependencies  related to all common facilities will
  provide
- add your facilities implementation  >>>Ex   @ControllerAdvice  ...
- in your main project will include it as a dependency